# How to pick a clan in Tap Titans 2?

Tags: tap-titans-2

If I search for clans I get 2 hits:

- Numbers of members in a clan
- Clan quests

What are those?

It seems to me that clan quests are like random titan poping out. What's the effect? Increasing the size of cannons from clan ship? What?

Usually if I pick some random clan with 8 clan quests, every time there is a clan quest, it's done in 1 minute.
Then I look on the web and join a clan with 20 clan quests. This time I am the only one killing the titan.

[Another page](https://www.writerparty.com/party/tap-titans-2-ultimate-guide-top-20-tips-tricks-cheats-and-strategies-page-2/) talks about clan level or clan challenge:

> When you are deciding which clan to join, join the one with the highest challenge level that you can possibly find. The highest possible challenge level is equal to the amount of days that the game has been on the store. Hit the reload button over and over and over to refresh the clan directory if you need to.

What is clan challenge level? What is that supposed to mean?

Anyway, my maximum stage is 900. Actually I don't know for sure. How do I know?

Answer (score 1):

Clan Challenge level is number of Clan Quests Bosses killed by this clan. The higher this number the higher Clan Ship Damage you are provided - this means Clan Ship cannon shot every 8 seconds, but also everything that benefits from this damage (based on your skill point distribution it can be a number of things).

Clan Quest Bosses spawn every 12 hours - your clan has 12 hours to defeat them, you can enter the battle and tap for 30 seconds inflicting damage equal to your MS onto the Boss. (Power Of Swiping Perk is useful), after that you have to wait an hour or pay diamonds to fight again.

This means you should look for a clan with as many Challenges as possible - remember that a lot of clans will want people with higher max stage, that is highest stage you have ever been to. It is because your clan quest damage per tap is equal to number of your MS (Max Stage).

Comment: So basically I would need to balance the clan challenge and my ms