# How do I find out my maximum stage?

Tags: tap-titans

[How to pick clan in tap titans 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339041/how-to-pick-clan-in-tap-titans-2)

This says that some clan only accept some people with certain maximum stage.

How do I get that info.

I think I reach 1000 once. I forget. I want to make sure.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are asking?

Comment: Maximum stage. It's in the question. Say I have reached level 1080 in the past. Then I prestige and reach level 300. How do I find number 1080 written anywhere in the game.